# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable using python

Tags: python

I am working on xml file of 210mb size using python. The data contain Nonetype and it give error as "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
nsmap = {}
lis = []
for event, elem in etree.iterparse("data_1.xml", events=('start-ns', 'end-ns'), remove_blank_text=True):
    try:
        print event, elem
        ns, url = elem
    #filter(None, lis)
    except ValueError:
        nsmap[ns] = url
print nsmap


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-23b2c0b682e8> in <module>()
      4     try:
      5         print event, elem
----> 6         ns, url = elem
      7     #filter(None, lis)
      8     except ValueError:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Don't how to solve it. I just want to print the data. Even without using try and except method it show same error.

Answer (score 3):

The exception you catch is of `TypeError` and not `ValueError`. If you want to catch the exception, replace `ValueError` by `TypeError` or leave it blank (you will henceforth catch *all* exceptions). Note that you should not try to use `ns` or `url` in the `except` block since they are undefined.

The other solution to do is:

```
if elem is not None:
    ns, url = elem
    nsmap[ns] = url
```

Comment: or use a tuple `except (ValueError, TypeError) as e: ...`

Comment: Yes indeed. However, I don't see how it may raise a `ValueError` actually (perhaps I am missing a trivial case).

Answer (score 1):

Add a check for `None`

```
if elem is None:
    continue
```

Or do whatever you want to handle `elem` being `None` inside of the block